# UFW Rules and Tor

Tags: configuration, onion-routing, bridge

Would the following rules still allow Tor or would I need to add something? Also running DNScrypt with 1.1.1.1 in case that matters and I would also like to use a bridge.

```
~$ sudo ufw allow out on <interface> to 1.1.1.1 proto udp port 53 comment 'allow DNS on <interface>'
~$ sudo ufw allow out on <interface> to any proto tcp port 80 comment 'allow HTTP on <interface>'
~$ sudo ufw allow out on <interface> to any proto tcp port 443 comment 'allow HTTPS on <interface>'
```

Answer (score 0):

No this will generally not allow Tor. Tor relays specify their own ports. There are some commonly used ports for OR ports (ex: 443, 9010, etc), but relays are free to choose any ports they want. Instead you should allow all outgoing connections from the tor process. Since the tor process runs as the debian-tor user on Debian-based systems, you could allow all outgoing connections from the debian-tor user. For example, something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12499/iptables-pf-rule-to-only-allow-xy-application-user